# Horizontal Scrolling of Images in Actionscript (Touch friendly)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, mobile, touch

I am new to actionscript development and can't figure out where to start. Have mercy :)
I am trying to create a picture gallery in Actionscript (Flex would also do, but no Flash). Basically, it should be a horizontal list of images with captions below the picture. It should be possible to scroll through the images on a touch enabled device -> no scrollbars

I have looked into ScrollViewport put don't know how to implement a basic version in pure Actionscript.! I have included a small sketch

[image]

I have seen alot of solutions with a scrollbar. But I want something like on iOS where you scroll with your finger through the images.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why is Flex ok, but "Flash" isn't? Actionscript is just the language you use to control Flash objects...

That put aside, look into masking. I would create a movieclip that is wide enough to hold all of your images. I would mask that movieclip with a rectangle and then adjust the x position of the movieclip with the images.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I don't have Flash - only working with Flex. Second, I prefer coding stuff, and having all the gui in code so I can alter it without having to open another application :) Will your solution be scrollable with touch (finger)?

Comment: Yes, you could just use the mx components, that way all your ui objects are in the mxml file with ni requirements of other applications. Look up "mask" in flex documentary. If my answer was indeed the one you seek, think about approving it...